# Salesforce Process Builder corruption?

Tags: process-builder

Since the Spring 20 in our sandbox I've had to rebuild new process builders that were not responding to the decision criteria filters. The decsion node filter criteria was not passing so the actions to create a record never run. Strangely, I was able to create additional decision criteria in the same process builder using the same filtering criteria and those work. So I recreate all of the decision criteria and delete the old ones. Process builder then works. But this is not proper. Anyone else see this ?

Comment: It might be useful to look at the xml to see if there's anything different there than what's in the UI?

Comment: Thanks. Did that. Seems like when creating a brand new process builder they don't work until you create new decision nodes and build up the criteria incrementally. This just started to happen which leads me to think its' a Spring 20 issue. Did not see any known issues.

Comment: Did you check debug logs? Maybe something would have been logged to explain the behavior.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. Nothing really stuck out given the limited logging. Key is that when I added another criteria with the exact same filtering then that branch executed where the original that was still in place did not. This just started occurring.

Comment: Thanks again Kris and sfdc. Incredibly a slight trailing space character was the issue. Copy and paste is always a problem. Shows up in the xml diff with an old version.